# Activity on portrait and DialogFragment on landscape

Tags: android, orientation, dialogfragment

I'm trying to present a DialogFragment on landscape, but my base Activity is locked on portrait (android:screenOrientation="portrait"). I achieved the dialog rotation by doing it during its creation. But, when it is displayed it seems the container is in the old format (the width and height like before rotation) and the rotated dialog doesn't fit inside it. Besides, the container cuts the contents of the dialog.

```
public class MenuFragment extends DialogFragment {

  private final int mOrientation;

  public PlantsMenuFragment(int orientation) {
    mOrientation = orientation;
  }


  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plants_menu,
            container, false);

    if (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == mOrientation) {
        mRootView.setRotation(90);
    }

    return mRootView;
  }
}
```

I've already tried to set it in layout xml, but the result is the same.
How do I fix it? Or there is a better way to present the dialog in a different orientation of the activity?
thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Override setUserVisibleHint() in each fragment.

In the portrait only fragments:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity a = getActivity();
        if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

in the the portrait/landscape fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity a = getActivity();
        if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
    }
}
```

This will allow the whole activity to rotate in one fragment, but fix it to portrait in others.

Comment: Thank you Shaik! I tried your approach, but it doesn't work for what I am doing. Because the whole activity rotates, I need it to be steady and the dialog to rotate.